# React js :- Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Q. i want to setstate of every answer map an arrray.
please hep me out.
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

````js
const CreateQuestion = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [quesindex, setQuesIndex] = useState(0);
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [QuestionData, setQuestionData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    function () {
      getTestSeries();
    },
    [id]
  );

  

  const getTestSeries = async () => {
    try {
      const token = authContext.token;
      const response = await Api.get(`/user/getallquestions/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setQuestionData(response.data["getAllQuestions"]);
      } else {
        toast(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast(error.message);
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {};
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="mx-auto flex justify-center my-3 text-5xl font-bold">
        Test Series
      </h1>
      <div>
        {QuestionData.length > 0 &&
          QuestionData.map(function (ObjectData, index) {
            const {
              questiontext,
              questionImgURL,
              options,
              answers,
              description,
            } = ObjectData;
```
while setAnswer state on every loop
```
            setAnswer(answer);


            return (
              <>
                <div key={index} className="my-2 mx-5 md:col-span-2">
                  <div className="shadow  px-10 py-2  bg-purple-100 sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <div className=" w-full  space-y-6">
                      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                        <div className="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                          <h1 className=" flex text-lg font-medium  space-x-1 text-gray-700">
                            <span className="font-semibold text-lg">
                              {index + 1} .
                            </span>
                            {questiontext}
                          </h1>
                        </div>
                        {questionImgURL === "" ? (
                          <div />
                        ) : (
                          <div className="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                            <img
                              alt="question img"
                              className="max-w-full  object-cover max-h-40 border-2 border-red-500"
                              src={`https://api.microstudy.org/${questionImgURL}`}
                            ></img>
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                      <div className="mt-4 space-y-2">
                        {options.length > 0 &&
                          options.map((options, index) => {
                            const { id, optiontext } = options;

                            return (
                              <div
                                className="flex items-center justify-start "
                                key={index}
                              >
                                <input
                                  id={optiontext}
                                  name="options"
                                  type="radio"
                                  value={id}
                                  onChange={changehandler}
                                  className="focus:ring-purple-500 h-4 w-4 text-purple-600 border-gray-800"
                                />
                                <label
                                  htmlFor={optiontext}
                                  className="ml-3 block text-base font-medium   text-gray-900"
                                >
                                  {optiontext}
                                </label>
                              </div>
                            );
                          })}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
        <div className=" text-center my-3">
          <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            className="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-8 border border-transparent shadow-md text-lg font-semibold rounded-md text-gray-900 bg-purple-400 hover:bg-purple-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
````

```
please Ignore  below text
```

Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: _"please Ignore  below text"_ - no, fix your question instead of posting garbage. Read [ask].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**

The error lies in the `onClick` prop of your button. In your current implementation,`handleSubmit` is being called in every render loop. To fix this, we can wrap the `handleSubmit` function in an arrow function, ensuring that it will only called if the button is being clicked.

**Your code**

```js
<button
  type="submit"
  onClick={handleSubmit}
  className="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-8 border border-transparent shadow-md text-lg font-semibold rounded-md text-gray-900 bg-purple-400 hover:bg-purple-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500"
>
```

**Fix**

```js
<button
  type="submit"
  onClick={() => handleSubmit}
  className="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-8 border border-transparent shadow-md text-lg font-semibold rounded-md text-gray-900 bg-purple-400 hover:bg-purple-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-purple-500"
>
```

Comment: Thank for your concern